# Angular Ionic 7 Local Notification with capacitor plugin - Daily notification is not working

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor, capacitor-plugin, ionic7

I have the same issue as many others here: I want to build a daily notification on which time is selected in frontend and want to execute a daily notification at the same time every day. I tried the repeats: true and every: 'day' here, but it didn't work for me. I tried this and searched everywhere.

I'm Using Ionic with angular on that am Using the Local Notification capacitor plugin.

Look for my code below.

```
 import { LocalNotifications } from '@capacitor/local-notifications';
 
 async setAlarm() {
    const now = new Date();
    const alarmDate = new Date(this.alarmTime);
    const alarmTime = new Date();
    alarmDate.setFullYear(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
    
    if (alarmDate <= now) {
      alarmDate.setDate(alarmDate.getDate() + 1);
    }

       await LocalNotifications.schedule({

      notifications: [
        {
          title: 'Alarm',
          body: 'Time to wake up!',
          id: 1,
          schedule: {
            at: new Date(this.alarmTime),
            repeats: true,
            every: 'day',
          },
          actionTypeId: '', 
          extra: null,
        },
      ],
    });
    
    alert('Alarm set for ' + alarmDate.toLocaleTimeString() + '.');
  }
```

The code above only sends out notifications at the user-selected times, but I need them sent out every day at the same time. Let me know if you have any references or suggestions.

I have tried this and searched everywhere.
I'm Using Ionic with angular on that am Using the Local Notification capacitor plugin.

I need Notification to sent out every day at the same time which user choosen. Let me know if you have any references or suggestions.